# Flutter populate listview with list selection (drill down)

Tags: dart, flutter

I need to "drill down" from a ListView, where, for example, selecting a State from a list should display a list of Zip Codes. Selecting a Zip Code should display a list of Cities, and so on.

I can find examples of selecting a list item and displaying detail about that item, but nothing about one listview selection creating another listview. In particular, is it preferable/possible to change the content of a single listview, or should there be a separate listview for each "level?"

This currently displays Zip Codes, based on a hard-coded State, but this is where I'm stuck.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      //gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
      //  crossAxisCount: 2,
      //),
      itemCount: zips.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Text(zips[index].zip,
        style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style.apply(fontSizeFactor: 4.0),);
      },
    );
  }
```

Thanks!

Comment: I see found State covered in Flutter doc, where it looks like I will find my answer. This question can be closed or deleted. Thanks.